# Applying for twice the same supervisors via different calls

Tags: phd, application, supervision

I am in the following situation:

- I have officially applied to some PhD position of some research institution (its for math and no research proposal was needed; so I didn't apply for any specific and pre-defined topic). This research institution is not a university, but rather an external institute for research, which has close collaborations with the university in the same town. Within the application, one had two specify his preferred supervisors and hence, I have chosen two Profs, in which works I am interested a lot, working at that university.
- Let me mention: Unfortunately, I have never been in touch with these Profs. I wrote an email to them before applying, but they never answered, since they are quite busy. Hence, I just decided to officially apply for the call in order to see what happens.
- Now, I have seen that another call was published very recently (approx. one month after the deadline for the application above). This call is NOT from the same research institution, but rather it runs jointly between two universities including the university from the two Profs mentioned above. Now, it happens that the two profs mentioned above are exactly associated to one of these universities and are also listed as possible supervisors. (again, the application is without a proposal, however, the research area is already specified as opposed to the application above, where I literally only applied for math and just wrote my interests and research experience in the statement of purpose.)

> **Is it appropriate to apply for this position too?**

Let me stree again: I do NOT ask for applying for twice the same position at the same university but with different projects, because clearly, I know that this is not really allowed. These are two completely different calls, from different institutions and with a different application procedure. It just happens that my two preferred supervisors are involved in both programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to apply for this position too?

Yes.